# Number of quarters between 2 dates

Tags: python, date

Let say I have 2 dates in below format

```
date1 = '2020Q1'
date2 = '2022Q4'
```

I want to calculate number of quarter between these 2 dates as integer.

Is there any method available to perform this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use pandas for this

```
import pandas as pd

print(len(pd.date_range('2020Q1', '2022Q4', freq="Q")))  # -> 11
```